# NLP: To remove verb and find the match in a sentence

Tags: nlp, nltk

Is there a NLP method like stemming, lemmatisation to figure out the below?

```
1=2 
3=4

1) provide technical documentation
2) technical documentation
3) use software design patterns
4) software design patterns
```

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you actually want to do! The readers shouldn't need to figure out what the question is, before they can actually figure the answer out for you.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by @hssay, your way seems to be PoS tagging and then removing verbs. If you don't want to get your hands dirty, you might prefer to use the off-the-shelf [Google natural language web API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/). If you try the UI, click on the Analyse button, and then under the Syntax tab, look for Part of Speech and VERB.

Another similar toolkit that you could use as an API is [StanfordNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanfordnlp/).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for "part of speech tagging". You can use any popular NLP library (check Spacy or NLTK) to do part of speech (POS) tagging. After that, you can eliminate tokens which have verbs as part of speech tags. POS tagging may not work well on very small sentences though.